# How UART handles spike or noise state change?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, serial-communication

In `UART`, the default state is `high` it will start the process when it receives `start bit` i.e, state change of `high to low`.

> My question is In some worst scenario any `spike, noise or interrupt` may
>   change the default sate from `high to low`which is enough for the `UART` to detect it as a start bit, So that it should not start
>   processing the next bits. I know `UART` internally handles these
>   scenarios and avoids the processing.

Can anyone explain me how UART behaves for this?

Comment: there is no one universal uart design that everyone uses, nor is there a standard that folks conform to for fault handling.  So there is no one answer to your problem..."it depends"...

Answer (score 1):

If the signal drop is short enough, the UART might not detect it as a start bit.  For example, a UART might oversample the line level at 16x the bit rate and when it detects a falling edge in the RX line will then look for a certain number of 0 samples in the next 16 to detect the start bit.  If it doesn't see enough 0 samples, it won't consider it a start bit (and might set some condition bit that indicates a noisy/dirty line).

But if the UART sees the line drop for long enough to consider it a start bit, then the UART will start processing as if a character is being received.  If the signal is "junk" this might result in:

- a spurious character,
- a framing error,
- a parity error (if the UART is configured to check parity),
- a 'break' signal (if the line stays in the low state long enough)

The datasheet for the UART device should give details on how bits are sampled & detected.

Answer (score 1):

`UART Receiver` samples the `Rx` line `16 times`(most uC's) before confirming the value of `each bit`. For example, if the baud is `9600`,each bit time will be `104uS`. Now to correctly detect the value of each bit(i.e whether its `high or low`), the UART receiver samples the bus every `104uS/16` seconds. The majority voting of these samples is then used to decide the value of a bit. The start bit is used to indicate to the receiver that data bits are about to be received. Its mandatory that the start bit be `low`.By employing such a sampling scheme, the receiver ensures that the effects of noise is eliminated.

Answer (score -1):

UART is an old, increasingly obsolete 1970s technology, so the error handling is poor. On the most fundamental level, the UART will trigger any read by a falling edge, which is the start bit.

So if there is noise which gets interpreted as the falling edge of the start bit, the UART will then sample 8 data bits, with sample times according to its pre-configured baudrate (usually it samples 16 times faster than the set baudrate). It will sample regardless of any edges present. After that, it will clock in a potential parity bit, and then 1 or 2 stop bits.

At the point where the stop bit is read, the UART checks to ensure that the parity bit (if present) is correct, if not, you will get parity errors. And then it checks the stop bit, which must be high, otherwise you get a framing error.

These kind of error checks are roughly of a fifty/fifty quality. Double-bit errors or larger will cause lots of problems. "Parity" in particular, is a poor method of detecting errors. Professionals stopped using it around 30 years ago. Overall, the error detection chance by hardware is very poor, by design.

This is why all UART-based protocols must have lots of checksums, sync bytes and other such overhead in order to work. UART is very vulnerable to EMI, to the point where you cannot reliably use UART buses outside a circuit board, without using differential signals (like RS-422).